# Paste and reformat text in Vim not via shortcuts but via commands

Tags: vim, reformat

I'm trying to write a script which would paste text from clipboard into Vim's current buffer, set the new textwidth value, new filetype and then reformat (gggqG key combo) this buffer according to these new settings.

Is it possible to reproduce all these actions as a sequence of commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following command. You can split its parts into a function, but also works from vim's command line.

This example inserts the content of the register `a` at the beginning of current buffer, set some options and format the whole script:

```
:0put a | set textwidth=10 | set filetype=python | normal gggqG<CR>
```

Comment: **Birei**, thanks, I didn't know that "normal hotkey<CR>" hint. The problem with the pasteing is that I want to paste from system clipboard (OSX has a special `pbpaste` command) -- but how to switch to insert mode with a command?

Comment: Use the `*` or `+` (e.g. `:put *`) register to paste from the system clipboard. If you vim is not compiled with clipboard support then you can do `:r!pbaste`. You should really recompile your vim to have clipboard support. Homebrew makes this easy.